# Libtool build issue

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf

I am using libtool in my project. When I run the following command :

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
src/Makefile
src/COMMUN/LIVRAISON/Makefile
doxygen.cfg])
```

I get :

```
configure: creating ./config.status
.infig.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile
Cant configure projet
```

I get the sources of the project from someone else.
So we have the same sources but he don't have the issue I have.

I tried to regenerate the configure file with the following commands:

```
aclocal
```

or

```
automake
```

And I get this issue:

```
aclocal: couldn't open `configure.in': no such file or directory
```

There is no configure.in in the project but a configure.ac.
So I think the project have an old version of  autoconf :
 (autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.63).
But I must keep this autoconf version.

I don't have any skill on this technology (libtool), does anyone know this issue.
Please excuse me if am not clear. I didn't write this script myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to run `autoconf` first

Comment: Same issue but thanks.

Comment: Autoconf 2.63 is nowhere near so old that it would require `configure.in` instead of `configure.ac`.

Comment: Note, too, that this appears to be an Autoconf issue, not Libtool, and certainly not C.

Comment: woopsiiiiiiiiie

Comment: In any case, the command to regenerate the configure script is `autoconf`, or, alternatively, `autoreconf`.  I usually recommend the latter.  It is very rare that you need to run the individual tools (`autoconf`, `automake`, `aclocal`, ...) directly, for `autoreconf` runs all of them that are appropriate.

Comment: Okey, autoreconf gives me the same issue when it execute aclocal.

Comment: This is the point where we say that there's not much we can tell you without a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I pulled a new version of the projet and the generation of the makefile worked.
So I can't explain what was the problem.